# How to merge multiple lists by their indices

Tags: python, list, indexing, merge

I want to combine a nested list (lists in it have different lengths) into one. I would like to add by index first. Then sort by size.

Example:

```
lsts = [
     [7, 23, 5, 2],
     [3, 8, 1],
     [99, 23, 9, 23, 74]
]

merged = [3, 7, 99, 8, 23, 23, 1, 5, 9, 2, 23, 74]
```

I would like to solve this without importing.

Comment: Have you tried writing a loop over the indices and using the `sorted` function?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list-of-lists cannot contain `None`s, you can do this with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

result = []
for row in zip_longest(*lsts):
    row = (x for x in row if x is not None)
    for x in sorted(row):
        result.append(x)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - But I would like to solve this without importing. I have also noted it in my post now.

Comment: Why not importing a set of standard tools that are very likely to be much more performant than hand-wirtten code? Is this perhaps a coding exercise or a school assignment? Otherwise I can't see a good reason to _not_ use standard library imports.

Comment: Indeed, it is a task primarily aimed at understanding logic. But I haven't been to school in a long time :')

Comment: FWIW, the docs for [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) list the Python equivalent of the code that doesn't use any imports. Ditto for [itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). You can use that to build a solution without actually importing anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner:

```
import functools
import itertools

functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [sorted(x for x in p if x is not None) for p in itertools.zip_longest(*lsts)])
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 99, 8, 23, 23, 1, 5, 9, 2, 23, 74]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - But I would like to solve this without importing. I have also noted it in my post now.

Comment: @red_joice  If you want to solve it without importing then it sounds like homework which you should try to solve on your own. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain the solution step-by-step with each building on the result of the previous step.

To group items from each list by their indexes, [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) is the tool for that:

```py
>>> import itertools as it

>>> MISSING = object()  # a sentinel

>>> lsts = [
     [7, 23, 5, 2],
     [3, 8, 1],
     [99, 23, 9, 23, 74]
]
>>> it.zip_longest(*lsts, fillvalue=MISSING)
>>> list(_)
[(7, 3, 99), (23, 8, 23), (5, 1, 9), (2, <object object at 0x7f529e9b4260>, 23), (<object object at 0x7f529e9b4260>, <object object at 0x7f529e9b4260>, 74)]
```

This groups list elements into n-tuples using the MISSING fill value where needed, because lists might not be of equal length.

The next step is to iterate over each n-tuple and sort it internally (while skipping the MISSING values). The built-in function [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) comes handy here:

```py
>>> list(
    sorted(x for x in ntuple if x is not MISSING)
    for ntuple in it.zip_longest(*lsts, fillvalue=MISSING)
)
[[3, 7, 99], [8, 23, 23], [1, 5, 9], [2, 23], [74]]
```

The final step is to flatten this sequence of lists, and we'll use [itertools.chain,from_iterable()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```py
>>> list(it.chain.from_iterable(
        sorted(x for x in ntuple if x is not MISSING)
        for ntuple in it.zip_longest(*lsts, fillvalue=MISSING)
    ))
[3, 7, 99, 8, 23, 23, 1, 5, 9, 2, 23, 74]
```

The good thing about `chain.from_iterable()` is that it doesn't repeatedly concatenate smaller lists into the longer and longer final list, making it efficient. It also does this at the C level, AFAIK.

It's worth noting that `None` can also be used instead of the `MISSING` sentinel, but I used MISSING to also demonstrate how `fillvalue` works (e.g. you might want to use a zero instead or something else, if you wish).

Answer (score 0):

[zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) makes the work. The rest is cleaning/formatting

```
In [1]: from itertools import zip_longest, chain                                

In [2]: lsts = [ 

   ...:      [7, 23, 5, 2], 
   ...:      [3, 8, 1], 
   ...:      [99, 23, 9, 23, 74] 
   ...: ]           

In [3]: [v for v in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*lsts)) if v !=None]        
Out[3]: [7, 3, 99, 23, 8, 23, 5, 1, 9, 2, 23, 74]
```